# Script to sequentially move 5,000 files at a time?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I created 1 million files that I'm trying to upload to a device. However, file explorer crashes if I select too many at once. I'm trying to break them up and move them into subfolders in batches of 5000.

The naming scheme for the files are `snowfile1.txt` - `snowfile1000000.txt`

The naming scheme for the folders are `snow1` - `snow200`

What script can I use to move files 1-5000 into folder 1, then repeat or for loop for the next 199 folders in sequence?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

---

EDIT: I figured it out! Thanks for recommending I use robocopy & encouraging me to figure it out my self. I actually learned something new!

Solution:

```
for ($i = 10; $i -lt 15; $i++) {
    ROBOCOPY (source) (destination) (file)$i.txt /MOV
}
```

Didn't get around to figuring out how to script it to do it for all my folders at once, but I'm getting close.

Thanks again!

Comment: use robocopy. It's made for. ;-)

Comment: I don't have much experience with robocopy, think you can elaborate a little more :/

Comment: At a PowerShell prompt, type in `robocopy /?` and press `Enter`, and read on. (Also, you can use a search engine?)

Comment: Right. I know how to find help on the cli & use a search engine, my issue is tying it all together to meet my need. No need to be rude, I thought this was a friendly place for questions :)

Comment: The best way to learn is get your feet wet trying. So set up some test files and folders and start to try. Read the help, try something, if it works try the next step ... that's how we all did it. ;-)

Comment: IMO he wasn’t being rude. And yes this is a friendly place for questions related to programming. The question should follow the sites clearly stated guidelines which include the minimum code possible from the code you’ve tried that demonstrates the problem as well as any errors or other helpful details. It is not a site for learning the basics about powershell or robocopy.

Comment: Understood. I started messing around with it, and ended up with a command that should work but doesn't for some reason. 


ROBOCOPY C:\Users\steph\Downloads\Snow\SnowFolder C:\Users\steph\Downloads\Snow\Snow1 [$(1..3 | %{"snowfile$_.txt"})]


I tested it with only the first 3 files. but it skips them for some reason. any advice? I'm still working it and researching it myself, however supplemental help from you guys is appreciated. Or if you can just point me in the right direction.

Comment: The first step would be to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70794110/edit) your question and add your findings there and the current issue you're facing, that way, anyone reading the question will see it and be able to guide you. If you add it to comment section someone reading the question might not be able to see it.

Comment: ok thanks. still trying to figure out stackoverflow

Comment: @stefmf welcome! this might (also) help: https://stackoverflow.com/tour